# "Save password for this website" dialog with ChromeDriver, despite numerous command line switches trying to suppress such popups

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the "save password" dialog when creating a ChromeDriver like this:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions --disable-extensions-file-access-check --disable-extensions-http-throttling --disable-infobars --enable-automation --start-maximized");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

And navigates to a login form and submit it.

How do I get rid of the popup?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add these preferences:

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
```

So your final code will look like this:

```
 var options = new ChromeOptions();

 options.AddArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions --disable-extensions-file-access-check --disable-extensions-http-throttling --disable-infobars --enable-automation --start-maximized");
 options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
 options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
 var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Is there any use of the password manager when running ChromeDriver? That user profile preferences should be default.

Comment: I never used the password manager in automation. Maybe someone uses it, but for me, it also looks strange that it is enabled in webdriver.

Comment: @TopGun Can you confirm if you are able to get rid of "save password" dialog through adding `options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);` & `options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);`

Comment: Ticking the answer was the confirmation, so yes, and thanks!

Comment: How to implement this on facebook/php-webdriver. I'm trying the below code but it doesn't seem to work

`$options = new ChromeOptions();`
`$options->setExperimentalOption('credentials_enable_service',false);`
`$options->setExperimentalOption('password_manager_enabled',false);`
`$caps = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();`
`$caps->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);`
`$this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create($this->webDriverUrl, $caps);`

Answer (score 3):

Here is this same solution adapted to Java, as used in my code. Adapting was non-trivial so sharing here in case other Java users read this:

```
        ChromeOptions chOption = new ChromeOptions();
        chOption.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        chOption.addArguments("test-type");
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
        prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
        chOption.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chOption);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is an implementation for Python users:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    'credentials_enable_service': False,
    'profile': {
        'password_manager_enabled': False
    }
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```