# How to disable chrome's "save password" popup in selenium webdriver (python)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to disable the "save password" popup in chrome in my selenium test whenever it appears. I found a way through ChromeOptions(), but can't find the argument or preference necessary to make the popup disappear.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("argument")
```

Comment: Have you tried [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223857/save-password-for-this-website-dialog-with-chromedriver-despite-numerous-comm). Look at the answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To disable the **`save password`** popup in **`Google Chrome`** within your Selenium Tests you can use the following piece of code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"credentials_enable_service": False,
     "profile.password_manager_enabled": False}
chrome_opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_opt, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: Was it your intent to overwrite the first prefs assignment?

Answer (score 5):

```
prefs = {"credentials_enable_service": False,
         "profile.password_manager_enabled": False}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

Works for me

Answer (score 4):

The below options will disable "save password" pop-ups. But this is in C#.

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
```

You can find the relevant options for python [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/options.py)

Answer (score 2):

A quick work around to disable save password popup in Chrome is to use incognito mode if it is an acceptable option to you.

```py
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above are working in my case , did anything change in this regard ?
I dont get a warning on the console either...

```
 prefs = {"credentials_enable_service":False,"profile.password_manager_enabled":False,"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is incorrect because it redefines the value of prefs and uses , instead of : to set the individual values.

The answer by user ItZzMJ works correctly. In my case, like this:

```
prefs = {"credentials_enable_service": False,
         "profile.password_manager_enabled": False}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```