# disable save password popup in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

here is my code

```
def __init__(self,username,password):
    self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    self.options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    self.options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
    self.options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    self.options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    #self.options.add_argument('--headless')
    self.options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    self.options.add_argument('window-size=1280,720')
        #lchrome = webdriver.Chrome(driver,options=options)
        #lchrome.minimize_window()

        #un = username
        #up = password
    time.sleep(3)
    self.lchrome = webdriver.Chrome(driver,options=self.options,)
```

how do i disable the annoying save password popup?
please help.
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable chrome's "save password" popup in selenium webdriver (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595113/how-to-disable-chromes-save-password-popup-in-selenium-webdriver-python)

Answer (score 0):

A quick work around to disable save password popup in Chrome/MsEdge is to use incognito mode. Here is the capabilities you can use with selenium grid:

```json
{
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
    "excludeSwitches": [
      "enable-automation"
    ],
    "useAutomationExtension": false,
    "args": [
      "--incognito",  # for Chrome
      "--inprivate",  # for MsEdge
      "--save-page-as-mhtml"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using below way.

```
from selenium import webdriver

    chrome_opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"credentials_enable_service": False,
         "profile.password_manager_enabled": False}
    chrome_opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_opt, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://google.com")
```