# Disabling 'Save address' chrome browser popups using C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Need help to block save address pop up  coming in chrome browser while executing selenium c# automation scripts.

[image]

Following all options already tried but no luck.

```
IWebDriver driver;
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-single-click-autofill"); 
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("--disable-infobars");
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalChromeOption("useAutomationExtension", "false"); 
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable chrome's "save password" popup in selenium webdriver (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595113/how-to-disable-chromes-save-password-popup-in-selenium-webdriver-python)

Comment: I used this to block username password save pop up which is working but Save address is still coming beacsue of which script failing.

Comment: Curious: How does the popup make your script fail? "Save address?" is popping up in my scripts too, but it doesn't seem to disrupt the script.

Comment: After analysis script is not failing because of this pop up (failing due to some scripts and wait issues) but still unable to close  or prevent this pop up with above code.
Thank you for help and suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to turn off the Save Address prompt using AddUserProfilePreference. It is called "autofill.profile_enabled". You can just add it to your ChromeOptions and pass those options in when instantiating the driver.

I got the name from this Reddit post:
https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/yicwf0/chromium_how_to_disable_save_and_autofill_address/

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
            options.AddArgument("test-type");
            options.AddArgument("disable-notifications");
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("autofill.profile_enabled", false);

            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(240));
```